# Is there a better way than using subprocess::Popen (rust)?

Tags: rust

I want to have a menu where a user can call functions, and stop them when they choose. I know one way of doing this is using `subprocess::Popen` and killing the processes with their pids, but I feel there is a better way to do this. It should be noted that the functions loop indefinitely (`loop { /* stuff */ }`) , unless somehow stopped.

Edit: Changed example, previous one was not very close to what I am doing:

(it should be noted that I don't intend to do anything with the result of the functions)

```rust
fn main() {
    fn lots_of_requests() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    
   

    loop {
    let _response = client.post("https://www.httpbin.org/post")
    .body("stuff")
    .send()?;
    }

    Ok(())
} 
}
```

Comment: are you looking for graceful exit from sub processes? If yes, are they your own processes?

Comment: I would prefer, and yes. Using the `Popen` method I would open executables. I would prefer to use functions defined in the source though.

Comment: could you post a simple example with code?

Comment: You can do it by [`spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html)ing a thread for your function, and having the function check a flag an breaking from the loop if the flag is set.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: The previous link already has examples in the doc.

Comment: My comment referred to your original code example. Given that you are doing web requests, I would suggest using the async API for reqwest along with tokio's [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.7.1/tokio/fn.spawn.html) to start your function an [`abort`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.7.1/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.abort) on the returned handle to stop it.